# High Reallocated Sectors Count and Current Pending Sector Count and Uncorrectable Sector Count, Is the disk dead?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, smart, hard-drive-recovery

I am using a raid 1 system. Yesterday one of the disks caused raid 1 degradation

Today i have connected that disk into another computer

From smart data of the disk I see the following problems

Reallocated Sectors Count : Raw data A50 : in decimals : 2640

Current Pending Sector Count : 78 : in decimals : 120

Uncorrectable Sector Count : 78 : in decimals : 120

Seek Error rate : 10CE63651 : in decimals : 4,511,381,073

Reported Uncorrectable Errors : 6

Command Timeout : 10002 : in decimals : 65,538

Here the full smart data taken from Crystal Disk Info 8.1.0 x64

Can i say that this disk is gone for warranty replacement?

```
ID Cur Wor Thr RawValues(6) Attribute Name
01 _70 _64 _44 000001371F33 Read Error Rate
03 _94 _93 __0 000000000000 Spin-Up Time
04 100 100 _20 00000000001D Start/Stop Count
05 _99 _99 _10 000000000A50 Reallocated Sectors Count
07 _83 _60 _45 00010CE63651 Seek Error Rate
09 _99 _99 __0 0000000005C1 Power-On Hours
0A 100 100 _97 000000000000 Spin Retry Count
0C 100 100 _20 00000000000F Power Cycle Count
B8 100 100 _99 000000000000 End-to-End Error
BB _94 _94 __0 000000000006 Reported Uncorrectable Errors
BC 100 100 __0 000000010002 Command Timeout
BD 100 100 __0 000000000000 High Fly Writes
BE _66 _59 _40 000022210022 Airflow Temperature
BF 100 100 __0 000000000000 G-Sense Error Rate
C0 100 100 __0 00000000000F Power-off Retract Count
C1 _99 _99 __0 000000000C75 Load/Unload Cycle Count
C2 _34 _41 __0 001600000022 Temperature
C3 _26 __6 __0 000001371F33 Hardware ECC recovered
C5 100 100 __0 000000000078 Current Pending Sector Count
C6 100 100 __0 000000000078 Uncorrectable Sector Count
C7 200 200 __0 000000000000 UltraDMA CRC Error Count
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the stat its clear that the disk is dead.

Comment: Ye i believe the same. Also from this another computer, which does not support bios raid, i am not able to set status of the hdd to non raid thus it is not visible in computer management > storage panel. Do you know how to set it to non-raid disk?

Comment: Why you want to change to non raid? Its dead. just insert the new disk to the raid system.

Comment: before sending to warranty i plan to erase it if i can for privacy reasons

Comment: You can use any disk wiping software like DiskGenius.